# Wix 3.11 "This action is only valid for projects that are currently installed" after rebuilding the project

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project, wix3.11

I have a WiX 3 setup project, using VS 2017 community with Wix toolset v3.11, install the output using:

`msiexec /i cient.setup.msi /lv output.log`

everything is good. uninstalling using

`msiexec /x cient.setup.msi /lv output.log`

is fine also. **BUT** if I rebuild the WiS setup project and then try and uninstall using the above command, I get the error 1602 from the MSI output. which is "*This action is only valid for projects that are currently installed*"

Here is the content of my `Product.wxs` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The name of the product -->
<?define Name = "Notification Client" ?>
<!-- The manufacturer, for setup package publisher and folder info -->
<?define Manufacturer = "MyCompanies IT" ?>
<!-- The version number of this setup package-->
<?define Version = "1.0.1" ?>
<!-- UpgradeCode must be unique and not changed once the first version of the program is installed. -->
<?define UpgradeCode = "{GUID-HERE}" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?define ClientService_TargetDir=$(var.ClientService.TargetDir)?>
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.Name)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Client.Setup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Name)" />
          <Component Feature="ProductFeature" Id="SetFolderPermissions" Guid="*">
            <CreateFolder>
              <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes" />
            </CreateFolder>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="StartupFolder" SourceName="Startup"/>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="StartupFolder">
            <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="*">
              <Shortcut Id="StartupShortcut"
                   Directory="StartupFolder"
                   Name="Notification Client"
                   Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]\NotificationClient.exe"
                   WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
           />
              <RemoveFolder Id="CleanUpShortCut" Directory="StartupFolder" On="uninstall"/>
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\NotificationClient" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!-- </Component> -->
      <Component Id="NotificationClient.exe" Guid="*">
        <File Id="NotificationClient.exe" Name="NotificationClient.exe" Source="$(var.ClientService_TargetDir)NotificationClient.exe" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="NotificationClient.exe.config" Guid="*">
        <File Id="NotificationClient.exe.config" Name="NotificationClient.exe.config" Source="$(var.ClientService_TargetDir)NotificationClient.exe.config" KeyPath="no" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Guid="*">
        <File Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="$(var.ClientService_TargetDir)Newtonsoft.Json.dll" KeyPath="no" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Notifications.dll" Guid="*">
        <File Id="Notifications.dll" Name="Notifications.dll" Source="$(var.ClientService_TargetDir)Notifications.dll" KeyPath="no" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="OHR_StdFunctions.dll" Guid="*">
        <File Id="OHR_StdFunctions.dll" Name="OHR_StdFunctions.dll" Source="$(var.ClientService_TargetDir)OHR_StdFunctions.dll" KeyPath="no" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="OHR_MSGraph.dll" Guid="*">
        <File Id="OHR_MSGraph.dll" Name="OHR_MSGraph.dll" Source="$(var.ClientService_TargetDir)OHR_MSGraph.dll" KeyPath="no" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="ServiceInstallation" Guid="*">
        <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
        <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have a feeling it is to do with a GUID issue, but I have followed the guidelines in other posts about uppercasing GUIDs and having the product Id re-generate every time to ensure upgrades can be rolled out without issues.

I'm new to Wix (this is my first project) therefore please be kind! :)

Comment: You can only uninstall an installed version. If you rebuild your project with Product Id="*" it is a different installation and thus not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the Product GUID to auto-generate (which is fine). This means that every MSI you compile will have a new product GUID - naturally. You can invoke your MSI uninstall either via a specified MSI file or by specifying the product GUID to uninstall. See this little "reference" for information on this, your section would be **section 3**: **[Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)** (this answer is a little long, please just focus on section 3).

**You are specifying an MSI file to uninstall in your command which is not the MSI that is currently installed on the box - hence the product code embedded in the MSI is wrong for the current uninstall** (what is installed is one of your previous builds - with a different product GUID).

You can locate the original MSI that was used to install on the box (if you still have it), and then your command `msiexec /x cient.setup.msi /lv output.log` will work, or you can figure out what the product code for the installed product really is, and then you uninstall like this: `msiexec /x {PRODUCT-GUID} /lv output.log`. This will always work once you find the correct product GUID. This uninstall runs from a cached copy of your original MSI in `%SystemRoot%\Installer` (super-hidden folder).

Here is one way to find the product GUIDs for installed products: **[How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)** (this answer is also a little long, just look for the PowerShell command - it will do).

---

**UPGRADE**: If you don't create a new product GUID for each setup, then you can not use a major upgrade. What you get then is a minor upgrade. This has to be installed in a different way than a major upgrade. Most people use major upgrades since they are more flexible. You need to implement a major upgrade to make your newest setup silently uninstall the existing setup as it is installed, otherwise you get two entries in add / remove programs as you state.

Setting up a major upgrade: [How To: Implement a Major Upgrade In Your Installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html).

And I will add the link you suggest yourself: [How to implement WiX installer upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade/724098#724098).

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I thought that this was the case, so I have changed the ProductID to be fixed, and now I get a different error when going through the same process... "Another version of this product is already installed..." which doesn't make sense as I now have a fixed Product ID, my version and UpgradeCode are still the same. this wouldn't be a problem, but if keep the ProductID as auto, and I push out an update, it just adds another entry into the programs and features, instead of updating the existing entry. I understand why as the Product ID is different.

Comment: having had a look around i can, i have found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade/724098#724098) detailing how to uninstall old versions before an update, and inevitably a rebuild of the msi package. which solves my problem. so i will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: p.s. if you think my question would be useful to other new Wix users, please upvote my question :)

Comment: Yes, your question was pretty well formatted, but I have fixed it up a bit to eliminate GUIDs (they could otherwise be copied and you could get problems - GUIDs should never be re-used by others). Always remember to remove any such "[sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051210/129130)" from your sources posted online. Also, please consider up-voting all helpful answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade code is used to enumerate potential candidates to remove in lieu of a pending installation. When you rebuild, the `/Wix/Product[@Id]` is regenerated and hence this appears as a new product which simply can "upgrade" anything with the existing upgrade code that you maintain.