# 64-bit system copies dll files into SysWOW64 instead of system32 using WiX installer [SystemFolder] property

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I need to change a configuration file in C:\Windows\System32\ but wix installer copies it in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: What's a question? System32 is for 64-bit binaries, SysWoW64 for 32-bit, that's the guidelines. What does not work and what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a short illustration:

1. Set the Platform to **`x64`** in the [Package element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html).
2. For the hosting component set the **`Win64 attribute`** to yes, and install to **`System64Folder`**.

---

***1. Package Element***:

```xml
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />
```

---

***2. WiX WXS Snippet***:

```xml
<Directory Id="System64Folder">
  <Component Feature="ProductFeature" Win64="yes">
    <File Source="TestFile.txt" />
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

---

And a few things:

- Files installing to the System folder are generally supposed to be set permanent (validation error or warning if you do not)
- You should not install to the System folder if you can help it. What file is this?

Comment: is there a way to get the Win64="yes" auto-generated when using Heat?

Comment: It does not look like it does, no: [See here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/heat-exe-Add-attribute-Win64-quot-yes-quot-to-Component-elements-td4947690.html) - try the search and replace approach suggested? `Candle.exe` also supports the -arch switch, check its documentation by running `Candle.exe` without switches in a command prompt - not sure how well it works, but it allows you to set default architecture.

Comment: There are also new developments in newer versions of WiX that I haven't researched and there is WiX's commercial branch FireGiant's [HeatWave Harvesting feature](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/harvesting/) that I have also not tried. As you can tell I haven't looked at this for a long time, but [here is an older answer of mine on heat.exe issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755780/129130) (towards bottom). And [another old answer on "Paraffin" etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55977336/129130).

Comment: See Rob Mensching's blog for developments in WiX 4 (preview): [WiX Toolset v4-preview.0](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2021/5/17/wix-toolset-v4-preview.0/) - where `candle.exe` and `light.exe` seem to have been merged. I am not sure what else has happened or if `heat.exe` is affected.

Comment: Tried -arch, didn't seem to make a difference.  Can't use paraffin, this is a company server.  :/  Search and replace seems so... ugh.  Whats the point of using Wix then?  If I'm going to be writing custom scripts, I might as well just roll my own installer, dispense with all this GUID nonsense.