# Application is not getting opened after installing it with the installer created by "Visual studio installer"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have created setup file using visual studio 2017. When I installed it in my system it was installed properly and worked properly. But I am trying to install in some other system than set up gets installed properly but when user tries to open it then it does not opened.

When I checked it in event viewer it gives following error.

I got following error in event viewer(.Net runtime)

Application: FaultyStatus.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.String) at DevExpress.Utils.AssemblyHelper.GetAssembly(System.String) at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Theme.GetAssembly() at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Theme.get_Assembly() at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedElementsDictionary.GetThemeAssembly(System.String) at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedElementsDictionary.ForceThemeKeysLoading(System.String) at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.ChangeTheme(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, System.String) at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.ThemeNamePropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean) at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object) at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXMessageBox.ShowCore(DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXMessageBoxCreator, System.Windows.FrameworkElement, System.String, System.String, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions, DevExpress.Xpf.Core.FloatingMode, Boolean, Double) at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXMessageBox.Show(System.String) at FaultyStatus.MainWindow..ctor() Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri) at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri) at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext) at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean) at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup() at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame) at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object) at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window) at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window) at System.Windows.Application.Run() at FaultyStatus.App.Main()
    Log Name:      Application
    Source:        Application Error
    Date:          4/04/2019 6:25:57 AM
    Event ID:      1000
    Task Category: (100)
    Level:         Error
    Keywords:      Classic
    Description:
    Faulting application name: FaultyStatus.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5ca3b1ee
    Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17134.556, time stamp: 0xadca2670
    Exception code: 0xe0434352
    Fault offset: 0x001118a2
    Faulting process id: 0x1ea8
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d4ea424abf8640
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vesta\FaultyProduct\FaultyStatus.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
    Report Id: d303086d-4bbf-4497-9c98-a71963842a88
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID: 
    Event Xml:
    
      
        
        1000
        2
        100
        0x80000000000000
        
        16288
        Application
        LAPTOP-GIILLVJT
        
      
      
        FaultyStatus.exe
        1.0.0.0
        5ca3b1ee
        KERNELBASE.dll
        10.0.17134.556
        adca2670
        e0434352
        001118a2
        1ea8
        01d4ea424abf8640
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Vesta\FaultyProduct\FaultyStatus.exe
        C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
        d303086d-4bbf-4497-9c98-a71963842a88

Comment: I have added .Net runtime error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved issue by looking the error log in Event viewer log file with the extension   .Net Runtime. issue was some of the dev express supporitng file were missing. Need to deploy all Dls using devexpress deploy tool.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE**: just some pointers:
>
> - Please be aware of [several limitations of Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130).
> - Maybe consider [alternative tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840).
> - And [a link to show the prerequisites view of VS Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704781/prerequisites-button-disabled-msi-installer/48706684#48706684).

---

Very common query that comes up all the time. Usually a **lacking runtime** or you have a **bad configuration setting** somewhere in your configuration files or registry settings. [Here is one comment of late on similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443127/how-to-make-windows-installer-application-or-exe-file-from-wpf-which-would-be-ab#comment97602734_55443127).

***Please check for the above mention issues first***, then maybe have a look at the below checklists (linked, and some inlined keywords). Verify very basic runtime requirements such as **`.NET runtime`**, [**`Visual C++ Runtimes`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and **`Java runtime requirements`** and similar, simple and fundamental runtimes first of all.

Just to inline the gist of it from the linked comment above:

- [**Debug common application launch problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530377/129130) (**`please do skim`**)
- [**Older version of the check list**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913)
- [Tools for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55413716/129130) (Visual Studio, ProcMon.exe ([rudimentary sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746076/registering-a-cpp-dll-into-com-after-installation-using-wix-msi-installer/47792474#47792474)), etc...).

***Keywords***: Missing Dependencies / Runtimes? (Java, .NET, etc...). Configuration Error? (pointing to UAT-server, etc...).  Encoding? Licensing? Drivers? Bitness? Permissions? Privileges? Registry Registration? Authentication / Authorization? Lockdown? (security software, etc...)

---

***Some Links***:

- [Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project - include VC++ 2015 Redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119157/visual-studio-2017-installer-project-include-vc-2015-redistributable/52121996#52121996)
- [Additional Setup in Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972797/additional-setup-in-visual-studio-installer-projects/50976968#50976968)