# Wix Installer hangs - verify that you have enough privileges to start system services

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-services

I'm trying to install a windows service using windows setup. Halfway through the setup hangs and never completes.

[image]

After a few minutes (4-5 mins) it throws the following error.

> verify that you have enough privileges to start system services

[image]

The install.log is stuck at here.

[image]

Service1.cs class

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceName = "MSPmateAgentService";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
        
    }
```

product.wxs file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MSPmate Agent" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.1" Manufacturer="MSPmate" UpgradeCode="2a2faae2-115e-4b45-aeeb-422663a2e357">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of MSPmate agent is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixSetUpProject" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomActionFormId" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.WixCustomForms.TargetDir)$(var.WixCustomForms.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="CustomActionFormId" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="PerformAuthentication" Return="check" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MSPMATEAGENT" Name="MSPMATE AGENT" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="MSPMATEAGENT">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
       <!-- <File Source="$(var.RMMSetUp.TargetPath)" /> -->

        <File Id='MSPmateAgentService' Name='MSPmateAgentService' DiskId='1' Source='$(var.RMMSetUp.TargetPath)' KeyPath='yes' Vital="yes"/>
        <ServiceInstall
          Id="ServiceInstaller"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Name="MSPmateAgentService"
          DisplayName="MSPmate Agent Service"
          Description="Agent service"
          Start="auto"
          Account="LocalSystem"
          Vital="yes"
          Interactive="no"
          ErrorControl="normal" />         
     
            <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
            Name="MSPmateAgentService"
            Start="install"
            Wait="no" />
        
            <ServiceControl Id="StopService"
            Name="MSPmateAgentService"
            Stop="uninstall"
            Remove="uninstall"
            Wait="yes" />

      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

am I missign anything here?

Comment: When it hangs, check in `Program Files\PMATE AGENT` to see if the windows service dll and its dependencies have been added into the folder. I suspect some of the dependencies might not be installed. I'm also not seeing where you have installed the config file.

Comment: Service startup errors tend to be caused by **`missing runtimes`**, **`little misconfigurations`** in the config files or **`incomplete installation`** (some of your own files are missing), **`bitness issues`** (32 vs 64) and **`not-elevated MSI running`** (no UAC elevation for install). And a few other things. The answer below has more on debugging.

Comment: How goes the battle?

Answer (score 0):

***In Brief***: Service startup errors tend to be caused by **`missing runtimes`**, little **`misconfigurations in the config files`** or **`incomplete installation`** (some of your own files are missing), **`bitness issues`** (32 vs 64) and **`not-elevated MSI running`** (no UAC elevation for install). And a few other things.

---

A recent question on services with solution: [Wix installer package containing a C++ Builder Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174368/wix-installer-package-containing-a-c-builder-windows-service)

---

***Suggestions***:

- ***Go Manual***: If you deploy this service manually (copy files in place manually), does it run properly on a clean box? To test for missing runtimes or misconfiguration. [Configure service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903256/129130). VBScript: [install service](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/services/scr_1017.asp), [other service tasks](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/services/).
- ***Verbose Log***: It looks like you have one, but for others: make a proper verbose MSI log of the installation. Here is how: [Different logging approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890). [Symantec KDB](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?legacyId=TECH98550).
- ***No Wait***: Have you tried to set the ServiceControl attribute **`"Wait"`** to **`"no"`** to allow the MSI to finish installing even if your service startup failed?

  - This should allow you to manually test the service startup via the Service control applet.
  - You can then also try [Procmon.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416186/access-to-path-denied-while-reading-a-dll-from-program-files-which-is-actually-g#comment105024050_59416186) to check what happens during launch.
- ***Debug Binaries***: Could you deploy debug binaries and attach the debugger? I haven't tried this for years. There could be new obstacles: [Interactive Services Detection Service Removed in Windows 10 (so no more Switching to Session 0)](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/interactive-services-removed-windows-10/).
- ***Folder Diff***: A quick trick: diff the folder that is working with the deployed folder that is not. For example between your main box and a virtual that has failed after clean installation.

---

***Samples***: WiX Service Installation samples:

- https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService
- https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX
- https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/

---

***Links:***

- [Tools for dependency scan / deployment debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940598/129130) (find what files should be deployed)
- [Application launch debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377)
- https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html

***Further Links:***

- [Deployment link collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)
- [Service Installation approaches (the good, the bad, the ugly)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903256/129130)
- [Wix - ServiceControl start takes four minutes to fail, should be 30 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340129/wix-servicecontrol-start-takes-four-minutes-to-fail-should-be-30-sec)
- [Wix installer based TopShelf windows service fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076477/wix-installer-based-topshelf-windows-service-fails-to-start)
- [Wix installer upgrade with same "upgrade code" ID shows privilege error prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703489/wix-installer-upgrade-with-same-upgrade-code-id-shows-privilege-error-prompt/57709473#57709473)